# Validating incoming requests in WSO2 API Manager 3.2.0

Tags: wso2-api-manager

How can I validate incoming requests in WSO2 `API Manager 3.2.0`? I want to for example check if json request body consist somthing, then not accept the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the `Threat Protection Feature`, you can use the `API Request Response Schema Validator` feature in the API Manager v3.2.0 to validate the request payloads. Find the relevant Doc here [API Request Response Schema Validation](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/api-security/api-request-response-schema-validation/json-schema-validator/).

Answer (score 0):

In refrence doc we can find solution for the problem :

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/api-gateway/threat-protectors/regular-expression-threat-protection-for-api-gateway/